# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method supportInvalidateOptionsMenu() from the type ActionBarActivity

Tags: android

i get error when call supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()  in my code :

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method supportInvalidateOptionsMenu() from the type ActionBarActivity

this my code (must static):

```
public static void reCreateSpinner(){
        supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        SpinnerMenuForm.clear();
        Variabel.total_unconfirmed=String.valueOf((Integer.parseInt(Variabel.hsd_unconfirmed) )+(Integer.parseInt(Variabel.mfo_unconfirmed))+(Integer.parseInt(Variabel.fuel_unconfirmed)));
        SpinnerMenuForm.add(new SpinnerNavItem(Variabel.total_unconfirmed,Variabel.hsd_unconfirmed , "Fill Order - HSD Bunker","HSD"));
        SpinnerMenuForm.add(new SpinnerNavItem(Variabel.total_unconfirmed,Variabel.mfo_unconfirmed , "Fill Order - MFO Bunker", "MFO"));  
        SpinnerMenuForm.add(new SpinnerNavItem(Variabel.total_unconfirmed,Variabel.fuel_unconfirmed , "Fill Order - FUEL Bunker", "FUEL"));  

    }
```

so how the right code ? thanks.. sorry for my english

Comment: Why does it need to be static? You need to call `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()` on a FragmentActivity class instance.

Comment: cause call from fragment (another activity)

Answer (score 0):

If you can pass in the FragmentActivity this method is attempting to manipulate:

```
public static void reCreateSpinner(FragmentActivity activity){
        activity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        SpinnerMenuForm.clear();
        Variabel.total_unconfirmed=String.valueOf((Integer.parseInt(Variabel.hsd_unconfirmed) )+(Integer.parseInt(Variabel.mfo_unconfirmed))+(Integer.parseInt(Variabel.fuel_unconfirmed)));
        SpinnerMenuForm.add(new SpinnerNavItem(Variabel.total_unconfirmed,Variabel.hsd_unconfirmed , "Fill Order - HSD Bunker","HSD"));
        SpinnerMenuForm.add(new SpinnerNavItem(Variabel.total_unconfirmed,Variabel.mfo_unconfirmed , "Fill Order - MFO Bunker", "MFO"));  
        SpinnerMenuForm.add(new SpinnerNavItem(Variabel.total_unconfirmed,Variabel.fuel_unconfirmed , "Fill Order - FUEL Bunker", "FUEL"));  

    }
```

The `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()` is available on `FragmentActivity` and its subclasses such as `ActionBarActivity`